# jira gadget production vs. development

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

I'm developing gadgets on my local development unit but I want to redirect my REST call to our production JIRA server. JSONP for sure doesn't work and won't work according to the Answers forum. The alternative to using JSONP I read is OAUTH. I couldn't find any good tutorial on how I can set this up in the Atlassian SDK/ developer environment.

Is there an alternative to to getting remote data? Or more resources anyone else knows of in regards to OAUTH?

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation on OAUTH here
https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+OAuth+authentication

Answer (score 0):

[Charles Web Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) might work since the calls can be done relatively but get proxied over to your Prod JIRA (Make sure you're already logged in there.)